# Cannot add new library path to .libPaths()

Tags: r, path, package

Hello I am trying to add a new path to .libPath() in RStudio in Windows. But it doesn't get added to it. Can someone please help me.

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/ars/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library"
> .libPaths(c(.libPaths(), "C:/Users/ars/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/"))
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/ars/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library"
>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the trailing slash. From `?.libPaths`:

> How paths new with a trailing slash are treated is OS-dependent. On a
>   POSIX filesystem existing directories can usually be specified with a
>   trailing slash: on Windows filepaths with a trailing slash (or
>   backslash) are invalid and so will never be added to the library
>   search path.

Comment: This has fixed the issue

Comment: @arshad if this is fixed, please consider to "accept" as answer.

Answer (score -1):

### Insert your desired path in quotes assigned to the path_to_libraries variable:

```
path.expand("~")
.First <- function() {
  path_to_libraries <- "" 
  .libPaths(c(path_to_libraries, .libPaths()))
}
```